# Symfony ManyToMany relation gets slower while importing big datasets

Tags: php, symfony

I'm facing an issue with my Symfony application. I have a ManyToMany relation which I need to persist and flush. However when the ManyToMany relation gets too big it becomes very slow on flushing the data to the database.

I've tried adding `fetch="EXTRA_LAZY"` however, this seems to have no effect.

My models look like this (i've removed some stuff which does not matter):

Image model

```php
<?php

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=ImageRepository::class)
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class Image
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=Content::class, inversedBy="images", fetch="EXTRA_LAZY", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $content;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->content = new ArrayCollection();
    }
    /**
     * @return Collection|Content[]
     */
    public function getContent(): Collection
    {
        return $this->content;
    }
    public function addContent(Content $content): self
    {
        if (!$this->content->contains($content)) {
            $this->content->add($content);
        }

        return $this;
    }
    public function removeContent(Content $content): self
    {
        $this->content->removeElement($content);
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Content model

```php
<?php
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=ContentRepository::class)
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class Content
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=Image::class, mappedBy="content", fetch="EXTRA_LAZY", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     */
    private $images;
    /**
     * @return Collection|Image[]
     */
    public function getImages(): Collection
    {
        return $this->images;
    }
    public function setImages(ArrayCollection $images): void
    {
        $this->images = $images;
    }
    public function addImage(Image $image): self
    {
        if (!$this->images->contains($image)) {
            $this->image->add($image);
            $image->addContent($this);
        }
        return $this;
    }
    public function removeImage(Image $image): self
    {
        if ($this->images->removeElement($image)) {
            $image->removeContent($this);
        }
        return $this;
    }
}
```

The importing process becomes fast if I uncomment the `$this->content[] = $content;` in the Image model. If I do not uncomment this line flushing data grows exponentially. I have replaced this with the preferred `$this->content->add($content)` Doing this haven't improved performance. (on both sides, for `Image` and `Content`).

We're running Symfony version 5.3.16 and this application runs on a machine with SSD's for de Database server, I assume this is not a hardware problem.

About the saving the content/image records.
We're flushing after every insert. Every 150 records we do a:

```php
$this->entityManager->clear();
gc_collect_cycles();
```

Does someone have an idea to push me in the right direction?

Comment: You could try `$this->content->add($content);` (this is done in newer Symfony versions anyways) not sure if it will make a difference but reading the [docs](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.14/tutorials/extra-lazy-associations.html), using `[]` may load the full array where add method doesn't trigger a full load. Even though the underlying method is doing this but on the elements of the ArrayCollection.

Comment: Hello Bossman. I have tried replacing the images[] and content[] functions with the preferred ->add method. Sadly this doesn't help.. The time to flush still grows exponentially

Comment: How are you flushing, in a loop? Are you batching the flush at all? Here is an [example](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.11/reference/batch-processing.html#bulk-inserts) from the docs.

Comment: We're flushing after every `processed` item.  In a batch we clear our memory with entityManger->clear(). The weird thing is that the first few minutes are good, and as soon as wel call `$this->content->add($content);` it starts to slow down.

Comment: Can you edit and post a simplified version of the code that is adding these?

Comment: I have updated the original post. I've also specified the cache clear batch size.

Comment: I see you said you're flushing after every insert, you shouldnt need to do that, you can do that in your batch of 150. Check the link I posted showing a batch update.

Comment: Hello Bossman. I've moved the flushing to the same part as clearing the cache. First flush, then clear the cache. Also this doesn't improve performance. The flushing time still increases..

Comment: Hmm, im unsure, try without `gc_collect_cycles();` if it is still the same maybe a [custom sql query](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html#querying-with-sql) call may solve your immediate issue for now.

Comment: I've tried it without the `gc_collect_cycles();` without any success. I think a raw query cannot replace the `->add` functions, since the items are not flushed so there is no identifier available to link them together. Or do you have any other solution?

Comment: The progressive slow down after few minutes makes me says it is a memory leak. You can access current script memory usage with `memory_get_usage()`. If the`gc_collect_cycles` is not enough to clear the memory, i would probably start thinking to split the batches on multiple processes (using cli command or symfony/messenger). Tell me if you want more details on that last point.

Comment: Make sure to run it without dev mode. Else every query is cached for debug purposes. On commanding add —no-debug

Answer (score 1):

I'll give you my view of your issue which can be discutable of course and i will be happy if people give counterview.
I've experienced such case in the past, and each time, the conclusion is the same.

To be honest, this is a typical example where the magic does not happen anymore when using Symfony / Doctrine.
And this is "normal".

Those tools are made to cover as much case as possible to improve developer efficiency to focus on making important things inside the codebase and not re-creating existing behavior. It lead to a 80-98% fast feature most of the time.

BUT

When performance needs to be improve even if code seems great, you will have to go back to more "manual" code. And yes using `Collection` feature on large dataset can lead to bad performance.

From my point of view you have multiple solutions you can try :

**1. Define the join table explicitly**

Instead of having a ManyToMany. Create the JoinTable as an entity.
You wont have to change your database if you properly create it.
See : https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/doctrine-relations/complex-many-to-many
for improved explanation. It simple two OneToMany relationship on your Content and Image entity with a new entity ImageContent with two ManyToOne.

This way you will be able to directly remove a relation between image and content in a much easier way.
For example:

```
$imageContent = $this->contentRepository->findOneBy(['image' => $image, 'content' => $content]); //very fast query since it used index
$this->entityManager->remove($imageContent)

// or to avoid multiple query : 

 $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('image_content');
 $qb->delete()->where('image_content.image = :image')
 ->andWhere('image_content.content = :content')
 ->setParameter('image', $image)
 ->setParameter('content', $content);
 
 $qb->getQuery()->execute();
```

And when adding

```
$imageContent = $this->contentRepository->findOneBy(['image' => $image, 'content' => $content]); //very fast query since it used index but you could do a count query to improve it more
if($imageContent){
   return; // so no duplicate occur;
}
$imageContent = new ImageContent($image, $content);
$this->entityManager->persist($imageContent);
$this->entityManager->flush();
```

This way you never have to play with the collection

Just be carefull to often clear entity manager while importing large dataset, look at my answer here : [Getting a managed and dirty entity error on persist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76127000/getting-a-managed-and-dirty-entity-error-on-persist/76130010#76130010)
for more precision about this, you fill some solutions to handle large dataset also.

**2. Use pure SQL**

If you do not want to try the upper solution. Just add or remove association in pure SQL called from repository. Something like that :

```
    $sql = "
    DELETE FROM image_content ic
    WHERE ic.image_id = :param1 AND ic.content_id = :param2
    ";

    $statement = $this->_em->getConnection()->prepare($sql);

    return $statement->executeQuery([
        'param1' => $param1,
        'param2' => $param2,
    ]);
```

Then you can do the same for insert also.

Well i hope it helped. Don't hesitate to ask question in comment.

Comment: Hello Thomas, thank you very much for the detailed explanation. I've tried to implement the suggestion number one. I created an ImageContent entity. This entity contains two ManyToOne's. One to the Content::class and one to the Image::class. I have also updated the Image and Content class itself with both a OneToMany towards ImageContent. The first 1000 items go well, after that I get an EntityManager is closed. Weird. Because the first 1000 items are correctly persisted.

Comment: try to lower your size of managed items to 100. To be honest, even 1000 by 1000 is too big for doctrine. 
Also, can you show us the code that do the import, it is more likely there is a problem inside it than inside the entities.

Comment: For testing purposes I'm flushing after every item. So 1000 items get correctly inserted in the database (one by one). After 1000 it's throwing me an error about entity manager is closed.

Comment: I need to see this code to help you.

Answer (score 0):

It happens because the calling method
`$this->images->contains($image)`
always load all of your collection to the ProxyObject to check the existence

https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-collections/en/stable/index.html#contains

https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.14/tutorials/extra-lazy-associations.html

After calling `$em->clear()` your collection always empty

try construction like:

```
$this->images->containsKey($image->getId())
```

it will load only the keys instead of all Image objects

Also check SQL logs in these place